# Reading one column of a csv file using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a file test1 which has 2 columns and about 2000 rows. i want to work on just 1st column. I am using numpy for the same but the program is printing elements of both the columns.
My data is like this:

```
59.806   -177.848
   -49.707     82.527
    54.281   -179.839
    93.360   -142.940
   -79.284     48.925
    50.487    173.136
.
.
.
.
.

   -60.811     66.818
    56.226   -178.830
    54.490   -175.354
   -63.786     52.221
   -65.698     52.403
   -45.539     71.237
    34.794    164.026
```

this is what i have tried

```
X = pd.read_csv('/home/psdlab/test1.dat')
x_data=df_numpy[:,0]
print x_data
```

And i am getting the following result

```
['   -49.707     82.527' '    54.281   -179.839' '    93.360   -142.940'
 ... '   -65.698     52.403' '   -45.539     71.237'
 '    34.794    164.026']
```

question : how to use numpy to print just 1st column.

Comment: Try changing the delimiter when reading your data file, from the default comma to multiple spaces: `X = pd.read_csv('/home/psdlab/test1.dat', sep='\s+')`.

Comment: Please provide more details of your code

Comment: use this method to read only one column pd.read_csv('/home/psdlab/test1.dat', usecols=col_index)

Comment: You also do't have a header row so can try: `df = pd.read_csv('/home/psdlab/test1.dat', sep = '\s+', usecols = [0], header = None, engine = 'python')`  To make into numpy array use: `df.to_numpy()` on the dataframe.

Comment: Try `arr = pd.read_csv("/home/psdlab/test1.dat", header=None, usecols=[0], delim_whitespace=True)[0].values; print(arr)`. You're reading the first row into the column labels, use the wrong seperater (you need whitespace), read too much (you only need the first column).

Comment: these are not working. i added sep ='\s+' and other things suggested.

Comment: Then there's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

first you must define the `np.arange` and `reshape` for the data. for example: `df_numpy = np.arange(4000).reshape(2000,2)`, because you have 2 columns and 2000 rows. After you define it, you can define `x_data=df_numpy[:,0]`, and finally, `print (x_data)`

Comment: 2000 rows is not exact. its an estimate. the data i am working with is biological data and i usually don't know how long it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your file reading `sep` in `pd.read_csv`. Currently, pandas is reading files assuming that each data row has a comma as a column separator. try this: `sep='\s+'`.